# netty 4.0.0.Alpha or 3.5.2.Final for new project?

Tags: netty

Can't decide for myself which version of netty should I go for in a new project.
Is there roadmap or release schedule for netty 4.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netty 4.0.0.Final should be out in about 2 month if everything work out. So depending on your project you can choose the right version for you. I would use 4.x but I'm one of netty's developers so this may be the reason why ;)

Comment: I've been using Netty 4 alpha for 2 years. Very happy to know it will be released in 2 months.

Comment: that is the plan.. so stay tuned ;)

Comment: Thank you. Sounds perfect. Will go for 4.x since the project is new.